How to renewunicodechar?
I like to use \newunicodechar (for example, as in the doc: \newunicodechar{♪}{\eighthnote}). But, how can I use it to redefine a character that already has a definition? Without generating a warning. For example, \newunicodechar{®}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}} spits out (as documented): “Package newunicodechar: Redefining Unicode character.”
I was expecting to find a command similar to \renewunicodechar to avoid the warning, but that doesn’t seem to exist.
I know about \DeclareUnicodeCharacter but I’d prefer using the unicode character, as permitted by \newunicodechar, and I know about \makeatletter \@namedef{u8:\detokenize{ū}}{\={u}} \makeatother but I’d prefer something less scary if possible.
So, in summary: is there a simple and readable way to properly redefine a unicode character?

well obviously the package doesn't provide this option. So either you have to use one of your work arounds and write your own \renew-command or make a feature request so that the package gets extended.

My idea is that the warning is important. Anyway, you can define \renewunicodechar by patching a copy of \newunicodechar.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%%% this is just for pdflatex, not for Unicode engines
\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy{\renewunicodechar}{\newunicodechar}
\xpatchcmd{\renewunicodechar}{\@ifundefined}{\@gobblethree}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewunicodechar{®}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}

\begin{document}

®

\end{document}


Thanks! Just curious, when writing “the warning is important”, do you mean that I’d better not define such a command, or that it’s a good thing that it’s not in the original package, or something similar? If so, which approach should I use to redefine ®, for example? Or shouldn’t I redefine ®?

@OlivierCailloux When writing the package, I decided that the warning is important in order to avoid surprises: I was wearing a copy-editor hat, I guess. There's a prototype newunicodechar3 package in the work that has a nowarn option.

If your nowarn option can be used for a single command, then it’s perfect! I certainly wouldn’t want to use a global nowarn option: I believe that warning a user who doesn’t know that a given command is defined already is important. However, I also believe that the user should be able to state: “yes, I know that this given symbol is defined already, let me redefine it please”. Similar to the newcommand / renewcommand approach .

@OlivierCailloux I'm not sure. While you're writing the document, the warning can be useful in order to avoid mistakes. When the document is ready, you can add the nowarn option to remove the warnings, but a copy editor can switch off nowarn and check what happens.

There is a problem here: with Unicode engine you can for example do \newunicodechar{®}{{\myfont ®}} where \myfont will select a font providing the character.  If you now use \renewunicodechar, for example mid-document (if allowed) to from that point on use \myotherfont that creates an infinite loop because the character is catcode active which it was not in first use.

edit: I had only tested in the preamble.  If in the document body the infinite loop happens at time of use of next® not at time of \renewunicodechar, but if in preamble it happens at time of \renewunicodechar.  Now the fix at user level will be to use \string ® in second argument of \renewunicodechar.

@user691586 \newunicodechar inside document is forbidden. If I ever add \renewunicodechar it would be disallowed as well. Anyway, the fix I proposed is just for pdflatex, not for Unicode engines.

@egreg A warning that shows up every time I compile to “warn” me about something that I know very well and am fine with (namely, that I am redefining ®) does not help to avoid mistakes. On the contrary, each such spurious warning reduces the probability that I see other (possibly useful) warnings (such as that I am redefining other symbols). That’s the reason that I want to get rid of warnings that I have decided are about harmless things. While I write, not afterwards (I fail to see the point of removing warnings once I stop writing, but that’s for another discussion I suppose).
